# Regex to search text file for domains

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the following code to find all domains (as best as I can) in a text file. Problem is it isn't finding any. I've tested the regex on regex101 and it was matching fine. Can anyone point out the problem? Tld.txt contains the full lowercase TLD list as I want to search for all of them.

**Edit:**
Tld.txt looks like this-

```
com
in
```

domains.txt looks like this-

```
mplay.google.co.in
play.google.com
```

Code

```
import re

with open("tld.txt", "r") as f:
    tld = f.read().splitlines()

with open("domains.txt","r") as f:
    domains = f.read().splitlines()
    for x in tld:
         regex = "^(.*?)"+str(x)
         for y in domains:
             domains_found = re.findall(regex, y)

print domains_found
```

Comment: add demo content from ```tld.txt``` and ```domains.txt```

Comment: Define _it isn't finding any_ - is there really _no_ output whatsoever?
 Also, `domains_found` gets overwritten. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the last result, since you are not adding results to `domains_found`, but replacing its contents. Have you just tried this?

```
import re
with open("tld.txt", "r") as f:
    tld = f.read().splitlines()
with open("domains.txt","r") as f:
    domains = f.read().splitlines()
    for x in tld:
         regex = "^(.*?)"+str(x)
         for y in domains:
             domains_found = re.findall(regex, y)
             print domains_found
```

Or better

```
domains_found.extend(re.findall(regex, y))
```